# Invalid resource in copy source ARN - while copying between the same accesspoints

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy a file from a source access point to a destination access point with the same url except a different file names:

e.g.

```
aws s3 cp s3://arn:aws:s3:eu-west-2:1234567890:accesspoint:my-access-point-name/path/to/local-1234567890.inprogress s3://arn:aws:s3:eu-west-2:1234567890:accesspoint:my-access-point-name/path/to/local-1234567890
```

Giving:

```
copy failed: s3://arn:aws:s3:eu-west-2:1234567890:accesspoint:my-access-point-name/path/to/local-1234567890.inprogress to s3://arn:aws:s3:eu-west-2:1234567890:accesspoint:my-access-point-name/path/to/local-1234567890
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the CopyObject operation: Invalid resource in copy source ARN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `:` with `/` just before the access point name worked!

```
aws s3 cp s3://arn:aws:s3:eu-west-2:1234567890:accesspoint/my-access-point-name/path/to/local-1234567890.inprogress s3://arn:aws:s3:eu-west-2:1234567890:accesspoint/my-access-point-name/path/to/local-1234567890
```

Strange `:` is fine if one of the source or destination is access point ARN but not both.